# highstock HighchartsPHP sql data - no chart showing

Tags: php, sql, highcharts

I'm trying to use the HighCharts/HighStocks library for the first time, via HighchartsPHP.

I am pulling data from my Postgres database, but I'm having problems getting a chart to display.  It appears the data is in the correct format, but it's still not displaying.

The timestamps come from the database in asc order already, so that's not the problem...

It seems I'm messing up one small part of the process...

Here is my script:

```
<?php

include "/data1/www/php/session.php";
include "/data1/www/php/database.php";
include_once "extra/HighchartsPHP/Highchart.php";

$max_rows       = 50;

$symbol         = "FB";
$db_conn        = pg_pconnect($_SESSION['conn_string']);
$db_query       = "select date, open, high, low, close, volume from stocks_prices where symbol = '$symbol' order by date asc";
$result         = pg_query($db_query) or die ('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());
$data           = pg_fetch_all($result);

$prices     = array();
$volume     = array();
$count      = min(count($data), $max_rows);
for ($row = 0; $row <$count; $row++) {
    $date       = strtotime($data[$row]['date'])*1000;
    $open       = floatval($data[$row]['open']);
    $high       = floatval($data[$row]['high']);
    $low        = floatval($data[$row]['low']);
    $close      = floatval($data[$row]['close']);
    $vol        = intval($data[$row]['volume']);
    $temp1      = array($date, $open, $high, $low, $close);
    $temp2      = array($date, $vol);
    array_push($prices, $temp1);
    array_push($volume, $temp2);
}

$chart  = new Highchart(Highchart::HIGHSTOCK);
$chart->chart->renderTo  = "container";
$chart->rangeSelector    = array('selected' => 1,);
$chart->title->text      = "$symbol Stock Price";
$chart->scrollbar->liveRedraw   = "true";
$chart->yAxis = array(
    array(
        'title'     => array('text' => "OHLC"),
        'height'    => 200,
        'lineWidth' => 2,
    ),
    array(
        'title'     => array('text' => "Volume"),
        'top'       => 300,
        'height'    => 100,
        'offset'    => 0,
        'lineWidth' => 2,
    ),
);
$chart->series[] = array(                       **# solution - remove the []**
    array(
        'type'      => "ohlc",
        'name'      => "$symbol Stock Price",
        'data'      => json_encode($prices),    **# solution - remove the json_encode()**
        'dataGrouping'  => array(
            'units' => array(
                array("week", array(1)),
                array("month", array(1, 2, 3, 4, 6)),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'type'      => "column",
        'name'      => "Volume",
        'data'      => json_encode($volume),    **# solution - remove the json_encode()**
        'yAxis'     => 1,
        'dataGrouping'  => array(
            'units' => array(
                array("week", array(1)),
                array("month", array(1, 2, 3, 4, 6)),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);


?>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>OHLC</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <?php
      foreach ($chart->getScripts() as $script) {
         echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . $script . '"></script>';
      }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/extra/highstocks/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            <?php echo $chart->render("chart"); ?>;
       });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the html source output when displaying the page:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>OHLC</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/extra/highstocks/js/highstock.js"></script>  <script type="text/javascript" src="/extra/highstocks/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 500px; min-width: 500px"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({"chart":{"renderTo":"container"},"rangeSelector":{"selected":7,"inputEnabled":"false","buttons":[{"type":"day","count":1,"text":"1d"},{"type":"day","count":5,"text":"1w"},{"type":"day","count":10,"text":"2w"},{"type":"month","count":1,"text":"1m"},{"type":"month","count":2,"text":"2m"},{"type":"month","count":3,"text":"3m"},{"type":"month","count":6,"text":"6m"},{"type":"year","count":1,"text":"1y"},{"type":"year","count":2,"text":"2y"},{"type":"year","count":5,"text":"5y"},{"type":"all","text":"All"}]},"title":{"text":"FB Stock Price"},"scrollbar":{"liveRedraw":"true"},"yAxis":[{"title":{"text":"OHLC"},"height":200,"lineWidth":2},{"title":{"text":"Volume"},"top":300,"height":100,"offset":0,"lineWidth":2}],"series":[[{"type":"ohlc","name":"FB Stock Price","data":"[[1337299200000,42.05,45,38,38.23],[1337558400000,36.53,36.66,33,34.03],[1337644800000,32.61,33.59,30.94,31],[1337731200000,31.37,32.5,31.36,32],[1337817600000,32.95,33.21,31.77,33.03],[1337904000000,32.9,32.95,31.11,31.91],[1338249600000,31.48,31.69,28.65,28.84],[1338336000000,28.7,29.55,27.86,28.19],[1338422400000,28.55,29.67,26.83,29.6],[1338508800000,28.89,29.15,27.39,27.72],[1338768000000,27.2,27.65,26.44,26.9],[1338854400000,26.7,27.76,25.75,25.87],[1338940800000,26.07,27.17,25.52,26.81],[1339027200000,27,27.35,26.15,26.31],[1339113600000,26.55,27.76,26.44,27.1],[1339372800000,27.18,28.07,26.84,27.01],[1339459200000,27.48,27.77,26.96,27.4],[1339545600000,27.66,28.1,27.1,27.27],[1339632000000,27.65,28.32,27.38,28.29],[1339718400000,28.51,30.1,28.35,30.01],[1339977600000,29.96,32.08,29.41,31.41],[1340064000000,31.54,32.18,30.7,31.91],[1340150400000,31.92,31.93,31.15,31.6],[1340236800000,31.67,32.5,31.51,31.84],[1340323200000,32.41,33.45,32.06,33.05],[1340582400000,32.86,33.02,31.55,32.06],[1340668800000,32.69,33.44,32.5,33.1],[1340755200000,32.46,32.9,31.9,32.23],[1340841600000,31.96,32.19,30.9,31.36],[1340928000000,31.92,31.99,30.76,31.1],[1341187200000,31.25,31.73,30.55,30.77],[1341273600000,30.91,31.44,30.8,31.2],[1341446400000,31.32,31.63,31.02,31.47],[1341532800000,31.44,31.9,31.26,31.73],[1341792000000,32.1,32.88,31.99,32.17],[1341878400000,32.43,32.48,31.16,31.47],[1341964800000,31.48,31.56,30.55,30.97],[1342051200000,30.7,31.4,30.6,30.81],[1342137600000,31.04,31.07,30.56,30.72],[1342396800000,30.5,30.5,28.21,28.25],[1342483200000,28.48,28.59,27.15,28.09],[1342569600000,28.31,29.29,28.15,29.11],[1342656000000,29.41,29.5,28.63,29],[1342742400000,29,29.47,28.72,28.76],[1343001600000,28.12,29,28.01,28.75],[1343088000000,28.82,29.45,28.1,28.45],[1343174400000,28.39,29.49,28.08,29.34],[1343260800000,27.75,28.23,26.73,26.85],[1343347200000,23.19,24.54,22.28,23.71],[1343606400000,24,24.04,23.03,23.15]]","dataGrouping":{"units":[["week",[1]],["month",[1,2,3,4,6]],["year",[1,2,5]]]}},{"type":"column","name":"Volume","data":"[[1337299200000,573576400],[1337558400000,168192700],[1337644800000,101786600],[1337731200000,73600000],[1337817600000,50237200],[1337904000000,37149800],[1338249600000,78063400],[1338336000000,57267900],[1338422400000,111639200],[1338508800000,41855500],[1338768000000,35230300],[1338854400000,42473400],[1338940800000,61489200],[1339027200000,26159500],[1339113600000,38034000],[1339372800000,28219600],[1339459200000,15816800],[1339545600000,17102800],[1339632000000,16855000],[1339718400000,43563800],[1339977600000,42978900],[1340064000000,30849000],[1340150400000,15553600],[1340236800000,21875300],[1340323200000,74834000],[1340582400000,24352900],[1340668800000,24858700],[1340755200000,28568000],[1340841600000,17713300],[1340928000000,19526900],[1341187200000,14122000],[1341273600000,8763600],[1341446400000,10032100],[1341532800000,10945600],[1341792000000,17785200],[1341878400000,14269500],[1341964800000,13030300],[1342051200000,11300700],[1342137600000,8108300],[1342396800000,24672100],[1342483200000,30438600],[1342569600000,16841800],[1342656000000,13685100],[1342742400000,11869100],[1343001600000,12390700],[1343088000000,11539800],[1343174400000,17230200],[1343260800000,64597400],[1343347200000,123102300],[1343606400000,29285900]]","yAxis":1,"dataGrouping":{"units":[["week",[1]],["month",[1,2,3,4,6]],["year",[1,2,5]]]}}]]});;
       });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you have 2 errors and one sort-of error:
Your `data` array must not be a string. Putting double quotes around it makes js treat it as a string.
Your `series` array has misplaced `[` and `]` characters.
There is an extra `;` at the end of the `chart` block (doesn't make it fail but not good to have).

I highly recommend a javascript "live" system to check your coding. I use jsFiddle and [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/ZB5sC/) is a working version of your code.

Comment: You gave me the clue.  All I need to do is remove the "[]" from the series array, and the chart showed up! (that, and I removed the json_encode() from the data array).   I knew it was a small error somewhere.  Thanks.